# DXA 1.2 Java Application caching using JMS remote synchronization

Tags: dxa, 2013-sp1, dxa-java

We are using DXA 1.2 Java and have enabled caching using JMS Remote Synchronization. Whenever we publish an item, the deployer `cd_cache` log is showing success as below:

> 2016-06-01 20:27:34,704 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 1  memSize = 446
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,755 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 2  memSize = 896
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,793 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 3  memSize = 1324
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,845 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 4  memSize = 1742
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,878 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 5  memSize = 2204
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,914 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 6  memSize = 2642
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,978 DEBUG LRUPolicy - Removing node with key 319:174400:172772
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,978 DEBUG LRUPolicy - Removing node with key 319:174400:172834
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,986 DEBUG LRUPolicy - Removing node with key 319:174400:172837
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,986 DEBUG LRUPolicy - Removing node with key 319:174400:174271
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,986 DEBUG LRUPolicy - Removing node with key 319:174400:174897
>   2016-06-01 20:27:34,986 DEBUG LRUPolicy - Removing node with key 319:174400:175153

But the application cache doesnt seem to get triggered and we are not able to see updated content and nothing comes up in `cd_cache` log of the application. cache log only gets updated if we recycle the application server (WebSphere Application Server). Both the deployer and application `cd_storage_conf` files have caching enabled and same `ItemTypes` caching enabled and object caching is also enabled. Can you please guide what can be wrong?

Application's `cd_storage` file required entries:

```
    <ObjectCache Enabled="true">
       <RemoteSynchronization Queuesize="628" ServiceMonitorInterval="10000" FlushCacheDuringDisconnectInterval="20000">
            <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Strategy="AsyncJMS11MDB" Topic="jndi/WCM_Cache_Topic" TopicConnectionFactory="jndi/WCM_Cache_Conn_Factory"/>
        </RemoteSynchronization>
    </ObjectCache>
    <Storages>
        <Storage Type="persistence" Id="WCM_Broker_DB" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" JNDIName="jndi/wcm_dev" />
    </Storages>
</Global>
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="WCM_Broker_DB" cached="true">
<Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Xml" sorageId="WCM_Broker_DB" cached="true" />
```

Enabled similarly for `.Txt` and `.Json`.

Application `ehcache.xml` entries:

```
<cache name="DD4T-Objects"
       eternal="false"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
       timeToLiveSeconds="300"
       timeToIdleSeconds="60"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
</cache>
<cache name="DD4T-Dependencies"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="50000"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
</cache>
```

Thanks,
Nipun